# Disabling boolean fields in Flask WTForms

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I know this is possible (because I have done it before!) but I cant find the correct syntax anywhere on the web including in the WTForms manual and in posts on here.

I want to disable a boolean field in a form.

In the template I have tried to add (disabled = "disabled") and (disabled = True) e.g.

```
<div class="col-md-6">{{ wtf.form_field(form.news)(disabled="disabled")}}</div>
```

and...

```
<div class="col-md-6">{{ wtf.form_field(form.news(disabled="disabled"))}}</div>
```

In the form definition in my Python code I have tried to add disabled = True e.g.

```
news = BooleanField(label=u"Search news", description="description", validators=[], disabled = True)
```

Every way I have tried throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

The field would be called with `disabled` to the form field. Here's some example code:

```py
import wtforms
class MyForm(wtforms.Form):
    my_field = wtforms.StringField()
f = MyForm()
print(f.my_field(disabled='disabled').__html__())
```

Output:

```html
<input disabled="disabled" id="my_field" name="my_field" type="text" value="">
```

If that's not working for you, I suspect the definition of `wtf.form_field` is perhaps at fault. I assume that's a macro you have.